# How to sort by two values in MongoDB-Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sorting

So I have a Ruby Script where I find all the documents with the type "homework" in the "grades" collection a "students" DB (MongoDB) The thing is, following these instructions:

**http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html**

I try to sort by score and then by student id (or viceversa) with:

```
homeworks.sort(:score, 1).sort(:student_id, 1).to_a
```

And running the file ("mongo.rb") I get an output of homeworks sorted by score (ascending) but not by student ID... (They're scrambled) If I try to switch values, I get the array ordered by student_id (ascending) but not by score... (In that case, score values are scrambled)

How can I Sort ascending by two arguments in mongo using ruby??

Comment: FYI just look at [this](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/490)

Answer (score 2):

Per documentation, try

```
homeworks.sort([[:score, 1], [:student_id, 1]]).to_a
```

Comment: Nope! same result... score it's ordered, student_id it's scrambled.

Comment: @Jmlevick: Are you certain? This should work if you do `collection.find(...).sort(...)`.

Comment: collection.find({"type" => "homework"}) thats what I'm doing... That is to exclude other documents types different than homework... But even using all the collection documents, the result is the same, one ordered, one scrambled...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
c = db['grades']
x = c.find({}, {:sort=>[[:student_id, 1], [:score, 1]]}).to_a
```

This works for me in irb.